# How to rotate the caret icon of select box when clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to replace the caret icon in select box with other icon and then I want this replaced image to rotate whenever I click on the select box.

I have successfully replaced the caret symbol with another icon. I'm stuck in rotating the replaced image.

Here is the code that I have written so far

```css
select{
width: 50%;
height: 30%;
appearance : none;
-webkit-appearance : none;
background-image : url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/slim-square-icons-basics/100/basics-08-128.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-position : right;
}
```

```html
<select>
<option></option>
</select>
```

As the image is replaced as a background image if i use the transform : rotate property the whole select box will be rotated. How should I rotate only the icon??

Comment: here is a working solution dude http://stackoverflow.com/a/37351567/4323504

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it.

Comment: Thanks  @TheFlash It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.wrapper select').on('focus', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
$('.wrapper select').on('blur', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
position: relative;
display: inline;
}

select{
width: 50%;
height: 30%;
appearance : none;
-webkit-appearance : none;
}

.wrapper:before {
content: '';
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 4px;
right: 4px;
background-image : url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/slim-square-icons-basics/100/basics-08-128.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
}

.wrapper.active:before {
transform: rotate(180deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
}

select:f
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<select>
<option>zxxdf</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: The image should not just change from down to up. It should rotate upside as animation

Comment: Try my snippet pls

Answer (score 0):

Iam saying that the icon you wanted to rotate will also rotate only when the anyone will click on the icon,just once you try this code otherwise if you want i can send the code with javascript function also

Answer (score -2):

With the rotate value, the element rotates clockwise or counterclockwise by a specified number of degrees. A positive value, such as 90deg, rotates the element clockwise, while a negative value, such as -90deg, rotates it counterclockwise.
i am sending the code write it as same with the name you had given after -webkit- you write this code

in your html file you write:

in css you do this:

```
.icon-name {
  background: mediumaquamarine;
  border-radius: 2% 50%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px;
  transition: all 3s;
  transition-timing: ease-in-out;
  width: 100px;


  &:hover {
    transform: rotate(1080deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to say @gunjan, The image should be rotated when someone clicks on it, not on hovering